# Can Polearm Gamble and Combat Agility be used together?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, fighter

So I just hit paragon with my hybrid paladin/fighter polearm fighter, and I took the hybrid feat again, and picked Combat Agility. I have rushing cleats on and have the Polearm Momentum feat as well as the Polearm Gamble feat.

My (and my DM's) question is, can they be used together?

Scenario: An enemy enters a square adjacent to me, triggering my Polearm Gamble. I hit him, push him 2 squares, and knock him prone. Can I then shift 1 square and hit him on the ground with the Combat Agility power? My initial thought would be no because you only get 1 opportunity action per round, but in all past versions Combat Agility granted extra OA's based off of your dex (my dex mod is 3), and in 4e it states that it triggers at the end of the enemy's action, so it's not an interrupt like Polearm Gamble's OA is. I've looked around online and I can't find anywhere that someone has asked about using these 2 powers together specifically.

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: Are you sure that is what Combat Agility did in previous editions? As far as I can tell that feat was called [Combat reflexes](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#combatReflexes)

Comment: I must have started searching Combat Reflexes during my search for info on Combat Agility.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing in either the Combat Agility feature nor the Polearm Gamble feat allow you to use a second Opportunity Action during a single turn.

For D&D the rules can change significantly with editions. The example that is relevant here is normally in 3.5e you only get 1 Attack of Opportunity per **round**, while in 4e you get 1 Opportunity Action per **turn**. The feat [Combat Reflexes](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#combatReflexes) was created as a way to increase the number of AoO you were able to take in a turn in 3.5e, but this ability wasn't necessary in 4e because you already get multiple Opportunity Actions per round.

Comment: I must have started searching Combat Reflexes during my search for info on Combat Agility. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Both [Combat Agility](http://dnd4.wikia.com/wiki/Combat_agility) and [Polearm Gamble](http://dnd4.wikia.com/wiki/Polearm_Gamble) are [Opportunity Action](http://dnd4.wikia.com/wiki/Opportunity_action)s.

Like you mention:

> A character can take any number of opportunity actions during a round,
>   but no more than one during each other combatant's turn, and none
>   during the character's own turn. Even if a character is able to take
>   two or more different opportunity actions, the character is limited to
>   one opportunity action of any kind per turn.

So you must chose which of the opportunity actions you wish to perform.

While the 4e **class feature** Combat Agility resembles the 3.5e **feat** [Combat Reflexes](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Combat_Reflexes) in name, they are mostly unrelated (besides concerning opportunity attacks).

Comment: I must have started searching Combat Reflexes during my search for info on Combat Agility. Thanks for the clarification.